# Bash script to check wether user have rw permission on given mount points or not

Tags: linux, shell

I am creating a bash script for checking no. of users does have r or rw permissions on given mount points. 
For this I am using below logic using touch command -:

`cat partitions.txt | while read line
do
part=$line
  su - demo -c "touch $part" 
fi
done`

Basically I am reading no. of partitions from a file partitions.txt and using touch command with user demo, if demo user doesn't have rw permissions on respective partition then it gives output like "permission denied" 
My question is how to check for this line or how to confirm wether the output of touch command contains "permission denied" error so that i can print this as output and tell that user demo doesn't have permission on respective mount points .

Can somebody help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

```
cat partitions.txt |while read line
do
    if [ -w "$line" ]; then
        echo "$line is writeable";
    else
        echo "$line is read-only";
    fi
done
```

Run this script as a user you want to check.

Comment: Thanks for the comment , well i figured it out as well :)